# AngularJS: $scope.watch not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an element `a` that stores the number of checked check boxes. It is updated in my partial. I have access to element in my controller, however, I need to make it global since it will be used by most of my controllers. I have used a `$rootScope` variable and have tried to set it to the value of the `a` everytime it is updated using `$scope.watch`, however, this is not working.

Partial:

```
<p>You have selected: {{ a =(categories | filter:{checked: true }).length }} JOSCOS</p>

    <ul class="a">
    <li ng-repeat="item in categories" >
      <input type="checkbox" class="chk" ng-model = "item.checked">{{item.info.ct}}
      </input>
      </li>
     </ul>
<a href = "#x1" ng-click = "al()">Start the test</a>
```

My angular controllers:

```
myApp.controller('OneController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('js/data/JOSCO.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.categories = data;
  });
 $scope.a = 0
    $rootScope.cat = $scope.a;
    $scope.$watch('$scope.a',function () {
      $rootScope.cat = $scope.a;
   });
   $scope.al = function(){
      alert($scope.a); //outputs properly
   };
}]);
```

Second controller(I have a different partial for this):

```
myApp.controller('DetailsController', ['$scope','$rootScope' ,function($scope, $rootScope) {

  $scope.catno = $rootScope.cat;
  alert($scope.catno);  //outputs as '0'
}]);
```

Comment: Are you missing to inject the `$rootScope` at the `OneController`

Comment: Um, I'm not sure. Im new to Angular. How do I do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$scope.$watch` accepts a number of different ways to specify what variable you will be watching. You can either specify a function:

`$scope.$watch(function(){return $scope.myvar}, someWatchHandler)`

or send in the variable directly:

`$scope.$watch($scope.myvar, someWatchHandler)`

or pass the variable in as a string:

`$scope.$watch('myvar', someWatchHandler)`

You are using the last one of these. Note that you do not need to prefix it with `$scope` -- if you do, it will not find the variable. Just remove `$scope` from `$scope.a` and it should work.